# `for` as a function instead of a macro

Tags: clojure

I'd like to have a `forall` function that acts like `for` but takes a list of sequences as inputs.

```
(forall (fn [arr]
            (prn arr))
        (range 10)
        (range 10)
        (range 10))
=> 
; [0 0 0]
; [0 0 1]
; [0 0 2]
;  ....
; [9 9 9]
```

Is there a good way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to map over the *cartesian product* of the input sequences, right? If so, you can create a lazy sequence of the cartesian product using for example the `clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product` function from the [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/) library and then map over that.

```
(defn forall [f & seqs]
  (map f (apply clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product seqs)))
```

This is a *function* that works more or less like the `for` macro when there are multiple sequences. Here is an example of calling it, and the result that you would obtain:

```
(forall (fn [arr]
          [:element arr])
        (range 3)
        (range 3)
        (range 3))
;; => ([:element (0 0 0)] [:element (0 0 1)] [:element (0 0 2)] [:element (0 1 0)] [:element (0 1 1)] [:element (0 1 2)] [:element (0 2 0)] [:element (0 2 1)] [:element (0 2 2)] [:element (1 0 0)] [:element (1 0 1)] [:element (1 0 2)] [:element (1 1 0)] [:element (1 1 1)] [:element (1 1 2)] [:element (1 2 0)] [:element (1 2 1)] [:element (1 2 2)] [:element (2 0 0)] [:element (2 0 1)] [:element (2 0 2)] [:element (2 1 0)] [:element (2 1 1)] [:element (2 1 2)] [:element (2 2 0)] [:element (2 2 1)] [:element (2 2 2)])
```

Note that in your example code, you call the `prn` function which is side-effectful, whereas the `for`-macro produces a *lazy sequence*. Combining laziness with side-effects is often discouraged because the side-effect may not happen when you would expect it to happen unless you know how lazy sequences work.

If you don't want to pull in the `clojure.math.combinatorics` library, you can easily implement your own cartesian product function, e.g.

```
(defn cart2 [a b]
  (for [x a
        y b]
    (conj x y)))

(defn my-cartesian-product [& arrs]
  (reduce cart2 [[]] arrs))
```

Comment: this is great. I didn't know what it was called.